# Failed review audit, but I think it's not an answer

Tags: discussion, review-audits, new-users

I failed [this review audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/9874741).
However, I think the answer is NOT an answer and should be a comment.

> In my opinion if you can guarantee that the parameter you working with will never contain a string it is safe but I would not do it in any case. Also, you will see a slight performance drop due to the fact that you are performing concatenation. The question I would ask you is why don't you want to use parameters?

What's the official verdict on this?

Comment: IMO you are correct and the audit is wrong. I have flagged that answer as NAA, let's hope the robo-reviewers are on point today.

Comment: Audits are based on a consensus. Consensus isn't always right. Accept this and move on :)

Comment: @IanKemp: It's not a great answer. In fact, it's little more than an opinion-piece. But it clearly passes the threshold of actually being an answer. Unfortunately.

Comment: If you remove the question from the answer, it's still an attempt to answer a question.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a great answer.
In fact, it's little more than an opinion-piece.

So, if you flagged it as VLQ or NAA, you were *wrong*.
But if you had downvoted, you would also have failed despite that being the right action, because the audits aren't that nuanced: GIGO rules.